# Meaning of hash in postfix configuration

Tags: email, postfix-mta, mail-server

I'm trying to configure my mail server. The MTA is postfix and in some configuration options is used hash in front of some statement.
example:

```
alias_maps=hash:/etc/aliases
```

Whay is it for?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:postfix-notation]. Off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix doesn't use the flat ascii files (well, mostly, that is), but uses a "hashed" for that allows quicker lookup/retrieval.

hash/btree are BerkeleyDB-type file based "databases".

This means, that Postfix doesn't actually use the file /etc/aliases, but rather /etc/aliases.db which is in turn generated by the "postalias hash:/etc/aliases" command.

Read more about how Postfix can use all kinds of databases (LDAP, SQL, and the like) here: 
http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html